# how many shuffles are there in a deck of cards?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I need to solve this question:

> How many shuffles are there of a deck of cards (52 cards), such that A$\heartsuit$ is not directly on top of K$\heartsuit$, and A$\spadesuit$ is not directly on top of K$\spadesuit$?

My solution:

For the shuffles' quantity, I'll get the total of shuffles of a deck and subtract from the number of shuffles that A$\heartsuit$ is on the top of K$\heartsuit$ and A$\spadesuit$ is on the top of K$\spadesuit$.
With this, we have: 
$$52! - 48!$$

is my solution correct?

Comment: No, it is not correct, but you are moving in the correct direction. Use inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: @user Ah, ok. I was lost in this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $52!$ shuffles in total.

There are $50!$ shuffles where the top hearts are on top of each other and the top spades too (merge them to create $50$ "combo/solo cards")

There are $51!$ of the type where only one of these pairs is on guaranteed to be on top of each other, once for spades, once for hearts.

So there are $51! + 51! - 50!$ (for the double counting where both are on top of each other) "forbidden" shuffles, and subtract that number from $52!$ to get the one you want.

So $$52! - 2\cdot 51! + 50!$$ as the final result.

Comment: it would be $52! - 2 \cdot 51! - 50!$ instead of $52! - 2 \cdot 51! + 50!$?

Comment: @MatheusSousa $--50!=+50!$

Comment: I'm sorry. Inattention of mine.